# Provide AngularJS 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to use provide in bootsrap but not working, here is my code:

```
import { NgModule, provide }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import {AboutComponent} from './about/about.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './account/login/login.component';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule,BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthenticationService} from './account/login/login.service';
import appRoutes from './app.router';

/**
 * Extending BaseRequestOptions to inject common headers to all requests.
 */
class CustomRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.headers.append('Authorization', 'my-token');
        this.headers.append('foo', 'bar');
    }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, appRoutes, FormsModule,
    HttpModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent, AboutComponent, LoginComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent,
  provide({useClass: CustomRequestOptions}) ],
  providers: [
    AuthenticationService
  ]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

I am geting error provide not defined. Anyone know what is problem and how to solve it? I am using last version of AngularJS 2

Answer (score 1):

There is no property on NgModule where you can simply pass in the results of a call to `provide`, you need to `provide` as part of your providers array like so...

```
 providers: [
   AuthenticationService,
   { provide: CustomRequestOptions, useClass: CustomRequestOptions }
 ]
```

Comment: I tried that also... but get error: `core_1.provide is not a function(…)`

Comment: Sorry, wrong syntax for `provide` you can get a lot more information here: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html